# New install of 20.04 LTS with AMD & Intel Graphics

Tags: drivers, graphics

Things are working, but a bit odd. YouTube videos are a little glitchy.

I've looked around, and I think it's installed the correct drivers... but I'm not really sure where to go from here.

It does seem like the graphics cards are recognized?

```
$ glxinfo -B
name of display: :0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
    Vendor: Intel Open Source Technology Center (0x8086)
    Device: Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 4600 (HSW GT2) (0x416)
    Version: 20.0.4
    Accelerated: yes
    Video memory: 1536MB
    Unified memory: yes
    Preferred profile: core (0x1)
    Max core profile version: 4.5
    Max compat profile version: 3.0
    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
    Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.1
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 4600 (HSW GT2)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 20.0.4
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile

OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 20.0.4
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)

OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.1 Mesa 20.0.4
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.10
```

```
$ sudo lshw -c video
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Mars [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8750M]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
       resources: irq:35 memory:90000000-9fffffff memory:b0900000-b093ffff ioport:4000(size=256) memory:b0940000-b095ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:34 memory:b0000000-b03fffff memory:a0000000-afffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff

$ lspci -nn | grep -E 'VGA|Display'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0416] (rev 06)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Mars [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8750M] [1002:6600]
```